# ejs multiselect push data

Tags: angular, syncfusion

I'm using multiselect and dropdowns from syncfusion. I'm using the dropdowns for selecting a property, load the property attributes and push them into the second dropdown, which works fine. Now I try to use a multiselcet for the of selected attribute values. But the data is not showing.

Strange thing is, that when I'm using the "debugger;" and go through the process it works..
It also works with a dropdown instead of multiselect.

```
<p>Set:</p>
  <ejs-dropdownlist id='property' [fields]='fields' (select)="onSelectProperty($event)" [dataSource]='propertyGroupsNames'></ejs-dropdownlist>
<p>Eigenschaft:</p>
  <ejs-dropdownlist id='attr' [fields]='fields' (select)='onSelectAttr($event)' [dataSource]='propertyGroupsAttributes'></ejs-dropdownlist>
<p>Wert auswählen:</p>
  <ejs-dropdownlist id='attr'  [fields]='fields' (select)='onSelectVal($event)' [dataSource]='propertyGroupValues'></ejs-dropdownlist>
<p>Neuer Wert:</p>
  <ejs-multiselect  id='multiselectelement' #checkbox [fields]='fields' [dataSource]='propertyGroupValues' [allowCustomValue]='true'></ejs-multiselect>




 // defined the array of data
  public propertyGroupsNames: { [key: string]: Object }[] = [];
  public propertyGroupsAttributes: { [key: string]: Object }[] = [];
  public propertyGroupValues: Object[] = [];
  // map the appropriate column
  public fields: Object = { text: 'name', value: 'id' };

 onSelectProperty(event){
    var selectedid = event['itemData']['id']
    this.propertyGroupsAttributes = []
    this.restApi.getPropertyGroups(selectedid).subscribe(data =>{
      data['data']['options'].forEach(element => {
         var ids = element['id']
         var nameP = element['name']
         var namePArr = {'id':ids,'name':nameP}
         this.propertyGroupsAttributes.push(namePArr)
      });
    })
  }
  onSelectAttr(event){
    debugger;
    var selected = event['itemData']['id']
    this.propertyGroupValues = []
    this.restApi.getPropertyGroupsValues(selected).subscribe(data =>{
      data.forEach(element => {
         var ids = element['id']
         var value = element['value']
         var nameValArr = {'id':ids,'name':value}
         this.propertyGroupValues.push(nameValArr)
      });
    })  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

While push the selected item into the datasource, parallelly add the item to the component instance using addItem public method, which adds a new item to the popup list.

```js
onSelectProperty(event) { 
    var selectedid = event.itemData.Id; 
    var selectedvalue = event.itemData.Game; 
    var namePArr = { ID: selectedid, Game: selectedvalue }; 
    this.propertyGroupsAttributes.push(namePArr); 
    if (!this.onInitial) { 
    this.listObj.addItem(namePArr); 
    } 
    this.onInitial = false; 
}
```

Sample: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qtfu49?file=app.component.ts